# Create Default Value For Expression<Func<TDto, object>[] In Runtime By Knowing the Type Only

Tags: c#, expression, automapper, automapper-6

i want to call ProjectTo dynamically
for example on this overload:

```
public static IQueryable ProjectTo(this IQueryable source, params Expression<Func<TDestination, object>>[] membersToExpand);
```

like this

```
Expression.Call(typeof(AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions), "ProjectTo", new[] { DtoType },'What goes here as arguments???')
```

This is the overload that i want to call

```
public static MethodCallExpression Call(Type type, string methodName, Type[] typeArguments, params Expression[] arguments);
```

Based on this link:
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2234#event-1175181678

**Update**

When i have a parameter like this

```
IEnumerable<Expression> membersToExpand = new Expression<Func<TDto, object>>[] { };
```

and pass it to the function like this it works :

```
Expression.Call(typeof(Extensions), "ProjectTo", new[] { typeof(TDto) }, body, Expression.Constant(membersToExpand));
```

But when the **membersToExpand** parameter is **null** it throw the exception
**No generic method 'ProjectTo' on type 'AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic**

So let me clear The Question:

The 'membersToExpand' have to be not null (OK i know that), when it's not null the 'Expression.Call' can find the suitable overload and it will success But the problem is when the 'membersToExpand' is null so i have to create the default 'membersToExpand' and i have to create it dynamically, i can't  create it like this

```
Expression.Constant(null, typeof(Expression<Func<TDto, object>>[]))
```

How to create this dynamicaly:

```
typeof(Expression<Func<TDto, object>>[]
```

when i just know the 'typeof(TDto)' ??

To reproduce the problem Just copy and Paste and then Run:

```
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<UserGroupDto, UserGroup>();
            cfg.CreateMap<UserGroup, UserGroupDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.UserGroupDetails, conf =>
                {
                    conf.MapFrom(ent => ent.UserGroupDetails);
                    conf.ExplicitExpansion();
                });

            cfg.CreateMap<UserGroupDetailDto, UserGroupDetail>();

            cfg.CreateMap<UserGroupDetail, UserGroupDetailDto>()
                .ForMember(dto => dto.UserGroupName, conf => conf.MapFrom(ent => ent.UserGroup.Title));
        });

        //  Someone Wants To Call WITH Members To Expand
        Start(new Expression<Func<UserGroupDto, object>>[] { e => e.UserGroupDetails }); 

        Console.WriteLine("===============================================");

        //  Someone Wants To Call WITHOUT Members To Expand (It's a pain to pass an empty 'new Expression<Func<UserGroupDto, object>>[] { }' so it's better to create the default, dynamically when it's null )
        Start(new Expression<Func<UserGroupDto, object>>[] { });

        //  Someone Wants To Call WITHOUT Members To Expand and pass it null and it will THROW Exception
        // Start(null); 

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Start(IEnumerable<Expression> membersToExpand)
    {
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            IEnumerable projected = CallProjectToDynamically(db.UserGroups.AsQueryable(), typeof(UserGroupDto), membersToExpand);

            foreach (var item in projected.OfType<UserGroupDto>())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" UserGroupID =>   " + item.ID);
                Console.WriteLine(" UserGroupTitle =>   " + item.Title);

                if (item.UserGroupDetails != null)
                    item.UserGroupDetails.ToList().ForEach(d =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" UserGroupDetailID =>   " + d.ID);
                        Console.WriteLine(" UserGroupDetailTitle =>   " + d.Title);
                        Console.WriteLine(" UserGroupDetailUserGroupName =>   " + d.UserGroupName);
                    });

            }

        }
    }

    static IQueryable CallProjectToDynamically<T>(IQueryable<T> source, Type dtoType, IEnumerable<Expression> membersToExpand)
    {
        // What i want is this:
        // if(membersToExpand == null)
        // Create The default dynamically For 'params Expression<Func<TDestination, object>>[] membersToExpand'


        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IQueryable<T>), "data");

        var body = Expression.Call(typeof(Extensions), "ProjectTo", new[] { dtoType }, param, Expression.Constant(membersToExpand));

        return (Expression.Lambda<Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable>>(body, param).Compile())(source);
    }
}
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("name=MyDbContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MyDbContextDBInitializer());
    }

    public virtual DbSet<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserGroupDetail> UserGroupMembers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserGroup>()
            .HasMany(e => e.UserGroupDetails)
            .WithRequired(e => e.UserGroup)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserGroupID);

    }


}
public class MyDbContextDBInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
    {
        IList<UserGroup> defaultStandards = new List<UserGroup>
        {
            new UserGroup() {  Title = "First UserGroup", UserGroupDetails = new [] { new UserGroupDetail { Title = "UGD for First UserGroup" } } },
            new UserGroup() {  Title = "Second UserGroup", UserGroupDetails = new [] { new UserGroupDetail { Title = "UGD for Second UserGroup" } } },
            new UserGroup() {  Title = "Third UserGroup", UserGroupDetails = new [] { new UserGroupDetail { Title = "UGD for Third UserGroup" } } }
        };

        foreach (UserGroup std in defaultStandards)
            context.UserGroups.Add(std);

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
public partial class UserGroup
{
    public UserGroup()
    {
        UserGroupDetails = new HashSet<UserGroupDetail>();
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserGroupDetail> UserGroupDetails { get; set; }

}
public partial class UserGroupDetail
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long UserGroupID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }

}
public partial class UserGroupDto
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<UserGroupDetailDto> UserGroupDetails { get; set; }

}
public partial class UserGroupDetailDto
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public long UserGroupID { get; set; }
    public string UserGroupName { get; set; }

}
```

Sincerely.

Comment: How would the call look like if done at compile time?

Comment: What `Expression.Call` overload are you trying to use? Don't see any with a  `Type` as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
var call = Expression.Call(typeof(AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions), "ProjectTo", new[] { typeof(Bar) },
                            Expression.Constant(source), Expression.Constant(null, typeof(Expression<Func<Bar, object>>[])));
```

But I think you're wasting your time. In the latest version, you're not even allowed to pass null.

Comment: Exactly, i know that, i can't pass null as membersToExpand,so i want to create a default value for null,BUT dynamically,i cant use generic as you said,faithfully yours.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by wrapping code into generic metod. When I use `ProjectTo<T>` I don't need to pass second argument. Here is my helper, it takes the type and list of fields and returns `DataTable`. `DB2` is `DbContext`.

```
public static class DTODataHelper
{
    public static DataTable GetDataOfType(DB2 db, string[] fields, Type type)
    {
        var method = typeof(DTODataHelper).GetMethod("GetData").MakeGenericMethod(type);

        var result = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { db, fields }) as DataTable;

        return result;
    }

    public static DataTable GetData<T>(DB2 db, string[] fields)
    {
        var dtoType = typeof(T);

        var source = Mapper.Configuration.GetAllTypeMaps().Where(i => i.DestinationType == dtoType).Select(i => i.SourceType).FirstOrDefault();

        if (source == null)
            throw new HMException("Не найден источник данных");

        var dbSet = db.Set(source);

        var querable = dbSet.AsQueryable();

        var list = dbSet.ProjectTo<T>().ToList();

        return GetDataTable(list, fields);
    }

    public static DataTable GetDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> varlist, string[] fields)
    {
        DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();
        PropertyInfo[] oProps = null;

        var hasColumnFilter = fields != null && fields.Length > 0;

        if (varlist == null) return dtReturn;

        foreach (T rec in varlist)
        {
            if (oProps == null)
            {
                oProps = rec.GetType().GetProperties();

                var excludedProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

                foreach (PropertyInfo pi in oProps)
                {
                    if (hasColumnFilter && !fields.Contains(pi.Name))
                    {
                        excludedProperties.Add(pi);
                        continue;
                    }

                    Type colType = pi.PropertyType;

                    if (colType.IsGenericType && colType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
                    {
                        colType = colType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    }

                    var piName = pi.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<DisplayNameAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()?.DisplayName ?? pi.Name;

                    dtReturn.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(piName, colType));
                }

                if (excludedProperties.Count > 0)
                {
                    oProps = oProps.Except(excludedProperties).ToArray();
                }
            }

            DataRow dr = dtReturn.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in oProps)
            {
                var piName = pi.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<DisplayNameAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()?.DisplayName ?? pi.Name;

                dr[piName] = pi.GetValue(rec, null) == null ? DBNull.Value : pi.GetValue(rec, null);
            }

            dtReturn.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dtReturn;
    }
}
```